# How can I add a Date Picker widget to a Date field in wagtailforms?

Tags: django, datepicker, wagtail

I'm using wagtailforms and have followed the example code at https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/contrib/forms/

This allows the content editor to define their own fields for a contact form, without the need for me to hardcode the form. One field the editor will add is a Date field. When this is rendered in the template, there is no Date Picker widget associated with it. I'm rendering the form as below -

```
    <form action="{% pageurl page %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

How can I add a Date Picker here? It's not 100% a Date field will be used, so I don't know the label of the field in advance, and there maybe multiple Date fields too.

My models.py has -

```
class FormField(AbstractFormField):
    page = ParentalKey('FormPage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='form_fields')


class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    thank_you_text = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        FormSubmissionsPanel(),
        FieldPanel('intro'),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', label="Form fields"),
        FieldPanel('thank_you_text'),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldRowPanel([
                FieldPanel('from_address', classname="col6"),
                FieldPanel('to_address', classname="col6"),
            ]),
            FieldPanel('subject'),
        ], "Email"),
    ]
```